# How to uppercase the Id of Entity Framework custom string primary key

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Using C# and Entity Framework Core

I created an entity with an Id of type string.
I would like to have that Id forced to be uppercase in the entity itself.

How can I do this?

I found this code to add in DbContext but it doesn't work, i.e. the foreach doesn't return anything.

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<GLAccountCode>())
    {
        if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified || entry.State == EntityState.Added)
        {
            // Possibly check for null or if it's changed at all.
            entry.Entity.Id = entry.Entity.Id.ToUpper();
        }
    }
    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Do you mean ChangeTracker.Entries<GLAccountCode>() is empty?

Comment: Yes it is empty, It doesn't enter in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have there certainly works.  I have tested it.  So maybe the problem is with the rest of your DbContext.  Here is the one I used.

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<GLAccountCode> GLAccountCodes { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"{my connection string}");
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries<GLAccountCode>())
        {
            if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified || entry.State == EntityState.Added)
            {                 
                entry.Entity.Id = entry.Entity.Id.ToUpper();
            }
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Note the DbSet property, you'll need that or otherwise some configuration code in the `OnModelCreating` method.